# File Indexing in Client Machine

Tags: xml, database, indexing

There are numerous networked files, distributed across many servers.

What is a better way to index those files on the client/local machine, XML or Conventional Database? Which would be easier and efficient to manage?

Considering only the attributes such as file name, file length, parent server etc. are to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're going to query them, how you will update them, how often they change... and on the relationships between items.

Most likely answer at first guess is actually a dynamic hashed database such as ndbm or BSD db. But it also depends on how you're going to connect to the index - from a C program. from a GUI, from a Linux command-line, what?

Comment: A `GUI` will be used to manage the indexing process and the database. At the same time, `GUI` will use the index to show the user which files are on the server. @barefootliam